# How do i find out where the json data comes given source code?

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping

Here is a part of a page source code. In my understanding this script parses json from some 3d party source being loaded along with the main page html.
Am i right? If so, how do i find out the name and location of this json file so I could load json directly without bothering to parse the html.

```
(function(XO, $, doc) {
'use strict';

window.XO = window.XO || {};

var storefrontInfo = {
  MarketPlace: {
    instagramHandle: '',
    isOutsideUsAndCanada: true,
    SegmentIO: {
      VendorInfo: JSON.parse('{\"vendorName\":\"Dreamlife Wedding Photo \\u0026 Video\",\"vendorAddress\":\"216 East 39th Street\",\"vendorAddress2\":\"\",\"vendorCity\":\"New York\",\"vendorState\":\"NY\",\"vendorZip\":\"10016-0000\",\"vendorFormattedPhoneNumber\":\"9173882835\",\"vendorUrl\":\"http://www.dreamlifewedding.com?utm_source=theknot.com\\u0026utm_medium=referral\\u0026utm_campaign=theknot\",\"vendorReviewCount\":\"84\",\"vendorId\":\"c2f5b7ea-82e1-4003-97b3-a41a00e7209d\",\"vendorCategoryCode\":\"WPH\",\"vendorCategoryCodeSlug\":\"wedding-photographers\",\"partnerVendorId\":\"555cb900-744f-4b82-b88c-cc2c4741c2d0\",\"vendorDisplayId\":\"841255\",\"partnerAccountId\":\"36585311-c9c1-443d-b7fe-16d5c7bfa645\",\"vendorMarketCode\":\"073\",\"settings\":{\"pricing\":false,\"tourAvailability\":false,\"editorial\":false,\"enhancedRfq\":true},\"vendorPriceTier\":null,\"vendorAdTier\":\"superior_paid\",\"vendorVendorTier\":\"FEATURED\",\"vendorBestOfWeddings\":\"[\\\"2011\\\", \\\"2012\\\", \\\"2013\\\", \\\"2016\\\", \\\"HOF\\\"]\",\"vendorClaimedStatus\":\"CLAIMED\",\"vendorPurchaseStatus\":\"PAID\",\"partnerAccountStatus\":\"Account\",\"vendorTransactions\":true,\"mediaSummaryCount\":117,\"photoSummaryCount\":117}'),
      RawVendorInfo: JSON.parse('{\"id\":\"c2f5b7ea-82e1-4003-97b3-a41a00e7209d\",\"accountId\":\"36585311-c9c1-443d-b7fe-16d5c7bfa645\",\"vendorId\":\"555cb900-744f-4b82-b88c-cc2c4741c2d0\",\"displayId\":841255,\"name\":\"Dreamlife Wedding Photo \\u0026 Video\",\"description\":\"Dreamlife Wedding Photos \\u0026amp; Video is a well-recognized wedding photography and videography company in New York City. At Dreamlife, we pride ourselves in providing clients with the best services and premium quality products at a fraction of competitors\\u0026#39; prices. We have a well-trained team of local photographers and videographers, with at least seven years of wedding and special events experience. Our creative, photojournalistic and traditional styles have attracted hundreds of couples every year. The high quality service, passion and commitment we offer our clients will ensure the moments of your special day are captured so that you may remember and share them for a lifetime.\",\"headline\":\"Top Choice for Wedding Photography and Videography\",\"movedProfileId\":null,\"websiteUrl\":\"http://www.dreamlifewedding.com?utm_source=theknot.com\\u0026utm_medium=referral\\u0026utm_campaign=theknot\",\"displayWebsiteUrl\":\"http://www.dreamlifewedding.com\",\"purchaseStatus\":\"PAID\",\"profileStatus\":\"LIVE\",\"claimedStatus\":\"CLAIMED\",\"accountStatus\":\"Account\",\"qualityTier\":\"NONE\",\"adTier\":\"PLATINUM\",\"vendorTier\":\"FEATURED\",\"location\":{\"address\":{\"address1\":\"216 East 39th Street\",\"address2\":\"Level 2\",\"city\":\"New York\",\"state\":\"NY\",\"postalCode\":\"10016-0000\",\"latitude\":40.74594,\"longitude\":-73.97952,\"isPublic\":true},\"serviceArea\":null},\"designers\":[],\"editorials\":[],\"photoSummary\":{\"photos\":[{\"id\":\"79024e00-7c49-449f-8bd8-a6cd00963d34\",\"width\":600,\"height\":400,\"type\":\"PORTFOLIO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/71d4c184-46ab-432e-a75d-5ce2457ea64a\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/a21b8f7b-0cee-457f-af0b-9f888e94ebb0\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"},{\"id\":\"f9d5ad84-6c53-4c44-b659-a6ca014d3489\",\"width\":600,\"height\":399,\"type\":\"PORTFOLIO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/b8127935-1647-4d87-a08b-874c08a3a8b8\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/57950d7b-3004-449e-ba29-0415b741bc76\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"},{\"id\":\"7e05d079-98fd-4127-a007-a6ca014d3489\",\"width\":600,\"height\":399,\"type\":\"PORTFOLIO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/99cd2fe7-4d9d-4af7-bacb-a41e2c074451\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/9cd0535f-a231-4325-b04c-674aff7f72a8\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"},{\"id\":\"13345975-845a-4927-9ccc-a6ca014d3489\",\"width\":600,\"height\":399,\"type\":\"PORTFOLIO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/735dac03-9f13-4a16-92fa-9c77548c9fe6\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/73172b78-b27a-45fe-87bf-453f1f51b8d8\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"},{\"id\":\"ce07c4aa-7714-4e8f-bfe9-a420008f9906\",\"width\":600,\"height\":399,\"type\":\"PORTFOLIO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/0f80c22d-8fe4-4bf8-8d58-604ec913ba93\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/2cf5650e-8726-4e70-ae55-65f39a25f154\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"},{\"id\":\"d54acc84-a71b-49c6-9c1b-a6ca014d3489\",\"width\":399,\"height\":600,\"type\":\"PORTFOLIO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/004eb23b-a0b8-4dac-afb3-b62911f0a85a\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/dd43acb8-e5aa-4a88-9d7d-bf68f2041e61\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"},{\"id\":\"4c63b22b-4d01-4ea9-8645-a6ca014d3489\",\"width\":600,\"height\":399,\"type\":\"PORTFOLIO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/f80d3a38-aaba-4e2b-9df7-df3ba2aac3a2\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/45e66b82-7ff7-4773-95ec-88dab116d26c\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"},{\"id\":\"4ac17b3c-5029-4738-8204-a6ca014d3489\",\"width\":600,\"height\":399,\"type\":\"PORTFOLIO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/f50aa1e5-87d8-4825-b0f4-84b8ea6c2026\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/8a9e553e-54a7-4e6e-9a40-1424a10dccfc\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"},{\"id\":\"6e7f7a18-6579-464f-a71e-a6ca014d3489\",\"width\":600,\"height\":407,\"type\":\"PORTFOLIO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/2421eca1-cb7a-430d-9fc4-e6c1033fae6c\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/3efed0de-6d95-47a6-b79f-d480480228fc\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"},{\"id\":\"17e39296-2bb4-4805-baed-a6ca014d3489\",\"width\":600,\"height\":399,\"type\":\"PORTFOLIO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/04805756-2597-4777-93fc-44262d6d889d\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/53001d95-8d16-48e6-9246-6e6c2d2a563f\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"}],\"total\":117},\"storefrontCard\":{\"id\":\"79024e00-7c49-449f-8bd8-a6cd00963d34\",\"width\":600,\"height\":400,\"type\":\"PORTFOLIO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/71d4c184-46ab-432e-a75d-5ce2457ea64a\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/a21b8f7b-0cee-457f-af0b-9f888e94ebb0\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"},\"logo\":{\"id\":\"8b005bcd-a325-435b-8b17-a420008f9905\",\"width\":100,\"height\":100,\"type\":\"LOGO\",\"url\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/027469ce-df4c-496d-a78b-e306c78ff8db\",\"originalImageUrl\":\"http://media-api.xogrp.com/images/a197f5de-7630-4c9f-9b48-687840e48c45\",\"mediaType\":\"PHOTO\"},\"emails\":[{\"address\":\"newyork@dreamlifeweddings.com\",\"type\":\"PRIMARY\"}],\"phones\":[{\"number\":\"9173882835\",\"extension\":null,\"type\":\"PRIMARY\"}],\"socialMedia\":[],\"reviewSummary\":{\"count\":84,\"overallRating\":4.68,\"popularityIndex\":4.67},\"siteUrls\":[{\"siteId\":90,\"siteName\":\"thenewknot\",\"uri\":\"http://www.theknot.com/marketplace/dreamlife-wedding-photo-and-video-new-york-ny-841255\",\"relativeUri\":\"/marketplace/dreamlife-wedding-photo-and-video-new-york-ny-841255\"}],\"facets\":[{\"id\":\"9cba912b-cd78-41dd-a7af-9d8c84dd1397\",\"name\":\"Photo + Video Styles\",\"facets\":[{\"id\":\"e305d03e-8111-4766-9492-2481510b1738\",\"name\":\"Artistic\",\"description\":\"A videography and especially photography style that emphasizes the aesthetic elements of a scene. The Artistic style focuses less on capturing each of the moments/traditions of the wedding and more on capturing light, shadow, and other ephemeral elements for the sake of beautiful images.\",\"singular\":{\"slug\":\"artistic\",\"term\":\"Artistic\"},\"plural\":{\"slug\":\"artistic\",\"term\":\"Artistic\"},\"isSelected\":true,\"facets\":[]},{\"id\":\"ea1e048f-edcd-4be9-9f8a-88414d8486bc\",\"name\":\"Documentary\",\"description\":\"A photography and videography style in which the photographer/videographer captures wedding events as they unfold, with minimal posing or intrusion. Typically, the photographer/videographer tries to blend in and be unobstrusive in order to capture the most natural, candid scenes possible.\",\"singular\":{\"slug\":\"documentary\",\"term\":\"Documentary\"},\"plural\":{\"slug\":\"documentary\",\"term\":\"Documentary\"},\"isSelected\":true,\"facets\":[]},{\"id\":\"d39ab780-fdd7-4703-b216-b3ed83382cac\",\"name\":\"Lifestyle\",\"description\":\"A style of photography/videography that mimics commercial advertising or magazine photo shoots (attention to backdrop/scene, close-up shots of details like rings and shoes). More dramatic and thematic than Classic, though both consist of posed images.\",\"singular\":{\"slug\":\"lifestyle\",\"term\":\"Lifestyle\"},\"plural\":{\"slug\":\"lifestyle\",\"term\":\"Lifestyle\"},\"isSelected\":true,\"facets\":[]},{\"id\":\"df59c6c1-194b-423d-a35d-a7073ca584ed\",\"name\":\"Modern\",\"description\":\"A contemporary photography style utilizing non-traditional angles (taken from above, focusing on a detail or body part such as feet, shots that integrate reflections) and/or urban settings. Often minimalist in style, using natural lighting.\",\"singular\":{\"slug\":\"contemporary\",\"term\":\"Contemporary\"},\"plural\":{\"slug\":\"contemporary\",\"term\":\"Contemporary\"},\"isSelected\":true,\"facets\":[]},{\"id\":\"28e84a55-277e-49ce-835c-2a6cabf80866\",\"name\":\"Vintage\",\"description\":\"Photography and videography styles that attempt to infuse a nostalgic and lo-fi (non-digital) feel to the wedding documentation. Likely to be shot using vintage cameras, plastic toy cameras such as Holgas, expired film, or where digital filters are added in post-production to lend an \'Ins…
```

Comment: The JSON source would appear to be right there, hardcoded in the script. If that is somehow not the case then try loading the page with the developer tools enabled in your browser and use the Network tab to see what resources are being loaded.

Comment: That data isn't coming from anywhere, it's right there in the code.

Comment: Thanks guys. Its a pitty.